# Intercepting/paralleles routes Application error: a client-side exception has occurred

Tags: next.js, next.js14

I'm working on a project with Next.JS 14 and I'm trying to set up a modal that intercepts the admin/dashboard/customers/[customerId]/ route in order to display the content in it (like producthunt).

My problem is that I get an error
Application error: a client-side exception has occurred

and in the console I get :
Uncaught TypeError: initialTree is undefined `The above error occurred in the <Router> component:`

I don't understand what's causing the error.

Translated with DeepL.com (free version)

I'm attaching a photo of my tree structure.
[arborescence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ2NM.png)

Here is my code:
admin/dashboard/@modal/default.tsx

```
export default function DefaultModalPage() {
    return null
}
```

admin/dashboard/@modal/(.)customers/[customerId]/page.tsx

```
const CustomerDialogPage = () => {
    return <div className="bg-red-600 p-12">CustomerDialogPage</div>
}

export default CustomerDialogPage
```

Since I want my modals to be in the dashboard, I put the modal call in the dahsboard layout:

```
import { LinkType, SideBar } from '@/components/layout/dashboard/SideBar'
import { FolderKanban, Home, Timer, UserCog, Users } from 'lucide-react'
import { PropsWithChildren, ReactNode } from 'react'

const LayoutDashboard = ({
    children,
    modal,
}: PropsWithChildren<{ modal?: ReactNode }>) => {
    const links: LinkType[] = [
        { name: 'Home', icon: <Home />, href: '/admin/dashboard' },
        {
            name: 'Customers',
            icon: <Users />,
            href: '/admin/dashboard/customers',
        },
        {
            name: 'Projects',
            icon: <FolderKanban />,
            href: '/admin/dashboard/projects',
        },
        { name: 'Hours', icon: <Timer />, href: '/admin/dashboard/hours' },
        {
            name: 'My Account',
            icon: <UserCog />,
            href: '/admin/dashboard/account',
        },
    ]

    return (
        <div className="flex h-screen">
            <SideBar links={links} />
            <div className="mx-4 mt-4 flex-1 overflow-auto rounded-lg bg-primary-foreground p-4">
                {children}
            </div>
            {modal}
        </div>
    )
}

export default LayoutDashboard
```

then I'd like to intercept this page:

```
import { CustomerForm } from './_components/CustomerForm'
import { Typography } from '@/components/ui/Typography'
import { Card, CardContent } from '@/components/ui/card'
import { getCustomerById } from '../customers.query'

export default async function CustomerPage({
    params,
}: {
    params: { customerId: string }
}) {
    const customer = await getCustomerById(params.customerId)

    return (
        <>
            <Typography variant={'h1'}>Edit {customer.companyName}</Typography>
            <Card className="mx-auto mt-8 w-2/3">
                <CardContent className="p-4">
                    <CustomerForm defaultValue={customer} />
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
        </>
    )
}
```

Just in case, here's the component that will take you to the customerId page

```
import { Typography } from '@/components/ui/Typography'
import {
    Table,
    TableBody,
    TableCaption,
    TableHeader,
} from '@/components/ui/table'
import { Plus } from 'lucide-react'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { ComponentType } from 'react'
import { Card, CardContent } from '@/components/ui/card'
import { CustomPagination } from '@/components/features/pagination/CustomPagination'

type ListPageProps = {
    title: string
    entryComponent: ComponentType<any>
    tableHeaderComponent: ComponentType<any>
    newLink: string
    data: any[]
    page: number
    totalPage: number
    baseUrl: string
}

const ListPage = ({
    title,
    data,
    tableHeaderComponent,
    entryComponent,
    newLink,
    page,
    totalPage,
    baseUrl,
}: ListPageProps) => {
    const EntryComponent = entryComponent
    const TableHeaderComponent = tableHeaderComponent

    return (
        <div className="container mx-auto p-8">
            <div className="mb-8 flex items-center justify-between rounded-lg bg-gray-800 p-4">
                <Typography variant={'h1'}>{title}</Typography>
                <Link
                    href={newLink}
                    className="flex gap-x-2 rounded-lg bg-blue-500 p-3 font-bold text-white transition-all hover:scale-110 hover:bg-blue-700"
                >
                    <Plus color="white" />
                    Add {title.replace('Page', '')}
                </Link>
            </div>
            <Card className="bg-primary-foreground">
                <CardContent>
                    <Table>
                        <TableCaption>
                            A list of {title.toLowerCase()}.
                        </TableCaption>
                        <TableHeader>
                            <TableHeaderComponent />
                        </TableHeader>
                        <TableBody className="text-base">
                            {data.map((item, index) => (
                                <EntryComponent
                                    key={item.id}
                                    item={item}
                                    index={index}
                                />
                            ))}
                        </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                    {totalPage > 1 && (
                        <CustomPagination
                            page={page}
                            totalPage={totalPage}
                            baseUrl={baseUrl}
                        />
                    )}
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ListPage
```

the entrycomponents

```
import { Pencil } from 'lucide-react'
import { TableCell, TableRow } from '@/components/ui/table'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { DeleteButtonWithConfirmation } from '@/components/layout/dashboard/button/DeleteButtonWithConfirmation'
import { deleteProject } from '../projects/[projectId]/project.action'
import { ActionButton } from '@/components/layout/dashboard/button/ActionButton'
import { deleteCustomer } from './customers.action'

export type CustomerEntryProps = {
    item: {
        id: string
        companyName: string
        email: string
    }
    index: number
}

export const CustomerEntry = ({ item, index }: CustomerEntryProps) => {
    return (
        <TableRow key={item.companyName}>
            <TableCell className="font-medium">{index + 1}</TableCell>
            <TableCell className="text-lg">
                <Link href={`customers/${item.id}`}>{item.companyName}</Link>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell>{item.email}</TableCell>
            <TableCell className="flex items-center justify-end gap-x-4">
                <ActionButton
                    id={item.id}
                    element="customer"
                    editLink={`/admin/dashboard/customers/${item.id}`}
                    deleteItem={deleteCustomer}
                />
            </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
    )
}
```

I've been blogging about it for several days without finding an answer to my problem. If anyone has any clues, thank you in advance.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Delete `.next` folder and re run the project.